# Candles by the amud

Tags: minhag, tefilla, synagogue, candle-lighting

Why do people light candles in shul by the amud during davening?

Is the custom specific to certain groups?

Comment: I've never heard of candles by the bimah, however I have heard of having them by the amud, to presumably cast light on the sha"tz's siddur. Presumably in schuls which have only a bimah, they serve the same purpose. See this photo of Orach Chaim in NYC for a modern example: http://gorlinarchitects.s3.amazonaws.com/9712-51.jpg

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt my bad --i meant amud.

Comment: Close relative: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47620/a-rabbi-asked-me-to-light-candles-before-weekday-mincha-maariv-is-this-customa